# polynomial equation results is not matching

Tags: polynomials

I have a data as follows
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Spend ($x$-axis)} & \text{Volume ($y$-axis)} \\\hline
10 & 40 \\
20 & 50 \\
30 & 52 \\
40 & 52 \\
50 & 53 \\
60 & 55
\end{array}
$$
The Chart will look as follow

[image]

I need to create an equation which derives the $y$ value based on $x$ value.
I used Excel to create a fourth order polynomial ought to do it.
And got the following equation

$y = -3\cdot 10^{-5}x^4 + 0.0044x^3 -0.2496x^2 + 5.9979x + 0.1688$

So as per my understanding if I pass $x$ value in the above equation, I should get my $y$ value.

As per that I passed $60$ as $x$ value. My expected output is $55$.

But what I am getting is

$y = -3\cdot10^{-5}\cdot60^4 + 0.0044\cdot60^3 -0.2496\cdot60^2 + 5.9979\cdot60 + 0.1688 = 23.0828$

Which is not correct, Can I know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't expect that a degree $4$ polynomial approximates the data for other values than the used ones. You can interpolate the six values with a degree $5$ polynomial.

Comment: used excel trendline option to build the equation

Comment: i have tried degree 6 but the result havent matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean you used Excel to do it?

The way to do it is to set up a fourth degree equation such as:

$y=ax^4+bx^3+cx²+dx+e$

You have $5$ unknowns, and you can use your $5$ first results to have a system of $5$ equations with $5$ unknowns... Which is easy, even if it is a bit tiresome.

The other problem is (or main issue in fact!), you have no way of knowing wether your results will follow an equation of the fourth order... It may very well be that there is no polynomial rule for your results... Or of a greater number... If this is the case, your result for 60 will always be different from your expected one.

Comment: got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772477/equation-for-a-graph/26776949

Comment: The problem is not foremost a mathematical problem. It is first a modelisation problem. Either you want a graph matching all your existing points (and for this a polynomial equation of degree $5$ will fit), or you want something that will somehow behave roughly like your previous points, and will allow you to anticipate further points. This is widely different. If this is the latter, you need to explain the prioblem, the behaviour, and then try to apply a model.